# Dailymotion Objective-C player not fullscreen

Tags: ios, dailymotion-api

I have dailymotion-player-objc 2.9.0 in my app and videos stopped to show fullscreen. It has always worked fine:

```
DMPlayerViewController *playerViewController;
[playerViewController loadVideo:@"x38n9ji" withParams:@{@"webkit-playsinline":@(NO),@"chromeless":@(YES),@"related":@(NO),@"quality":@720}];

- (void)dailymotionPlayer:(DMPlayerViewController *)player didReceiveEvent:(NSString *)eventName {

    if ([eventName isEqualToString:@"playing"])
    {
        ***// event detected but player doesn't enter fullscreen***
        playerViewController.fullscreen = YES;
    }

    if ([eventName isEqualToString:@"fullscreenchange"])
    {
       ***// event not detected player doesn't enter fullscreen***
    }
}
```

Using iOS 9.1 / App Transport Security - Allow Arbitrary Loads YES / DMPlayerViewController in Container View / Storyboard

Anyone with the same problem or any idea what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue on Dailymotion's side, it has now been solved so fullscreen should be back working now.

Comment: is there any sort of version or other info you could provide that could help people in the future?

Comment: what do you mean by version?